# Travis CI Job log is empty

Tags: elixir, travis-ci

I just set up [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) for the first time for [one of my Elixir Projects](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut) and it seems to work fine, except that the Job Log is empty.

I've tried:

- Googling
- Going through the Travis CI Docs
- Playing around with the `.travis.yml` configuration file

but have absolutely no idea why the log is empty. This is the **[Github Project](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut)** and the **[Travis Job](https://travis-ci.org/sheharyarn/ecto_rut/builds/172466781)**.

[image: Empty Travis CI Job Log]

---

My `.travis.yml`:

```
language: elixir
elixir:
  - 1.3.0
otp_release:
  - 18.0
sudo: false
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - cp config/travis_ci.exs config/config.exs
  - mix deps.get --only test
script:
  - mix test
after_script:
  - mix deps.get --only docs
  - MIX_ENV=docs mix inch.report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I picked quite the day to set up my first Travis CI project. After a bit more Googling and other fruitless pursuits, I came across a broadcast on their website:

> Build logs are currently not rendered properly or not rendered at all for open source builds. You can follow the updates on this incident here. Thank you for your patience.

Apparently this has been happening all day with other Open Source projects as well, and they have even logged an incident on their [**Status website**](https://www.traviscistatus.com/incidents/lp492hx0z1my). They're on the case and it looks like it'll be fixed in the next few hours.

---

**Update:** The Issue has been resolved.

Comment: Perhaps, similar problem in [**April 2017**](http://i.imgur.com/d94X5A7.png). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the problem also in Travis CI side. Now Travis CI successful work for me. Thanks.